# Creating Variable names Dynamically - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in a table by name color which has distinct values like "Red", "Green", "Blue",  "Yellow".

I need to know how to create the variable names dynamically by their distinct values.

i.e each variable name will be the value.

In the above case four variable names to be created i.e."Red", "Green", "Blue",  "Yellow".

to be clear

Basically it is declaring the variables in the declaring section where the variables names can be dynamic

Comment: and how will you use these variables if you don't know the names (if it's not dynamic query)?

Comment: Since PostgreSQL doesn't have "variables" as such, is there any chance you can explain a little more? Maybe sketch an outline of how you want the code to work?

Comment: Basically it is declaring the variables in the declaring section where the variables names can be dynamic

Comment: Repeating exactly the same sentence again is not considered "explain a little more". Apparently we don't understand that sentence, so you need to re-phrase it and give us more context on what you want to do. Ideally with some code that you tried and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the context is the `plpgsql` language, it's not possible to have dynamic contents in the `DECLARE` section.

Anyway, dynamically created variables are rarely used even when they're technically possible. In other interpreted languages, the common way to address the need for a variable number of variables is to use a `map` (perl) or an `array` (php) indexed by names as is they were variable names.

In `plpgsql` you may use the [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) type as the closest equivalent.

Example:

```
DECLARE 
  vars hstore:=hstore('');
BEGIN
  -- assign a pseudo-variable with name='Blue' and value='abc'
  vars:=vars||'Blue=>abc';
  -- load values from a query selecting names and associated values
   for color,val in select * from colors
   loop
     vars:=vars||(color=>val::text);
   end loop;
  -- Get the value of the pseudo-variable for 'Red', assuming it came out
  -- in the query's results
  raise notice 'the value for Red is: %', vars->'Red';
END;
```

The main drawback compared to real variables is that there's only one type for the content: `text`. The values need to be casted dynamically when `text` is not suitable.